# How can I find the limiting distribution of $Z_n=\sqrt{n}\frac{X_1X_2+X_3X_4+\cdots+X_{2n-1}X_{2n}}{X_1^2+\cdots+X_{2n}^2}$?

Tags: distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, convergence

> Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ be i.i.d random variables with $E(X_i)=0$,
>   $Var(X_i)=1$, and $E(X_i^4)<\infty$. How can I find the limiting
>   distribution of
>   $Z_n=\sqrt{n}\frac{X_1X_2+X_3X_4+\cdots+X_{2n-1}X_{2n}}{X_1^2+\cdots+X_{2n}^2}$?

**My thoughts:**

I am a bit confused on why $E(X_i^4)<\infty$ was included in the prompt for this question. In class, I worked out several examples similar to this question, but the distribution for the random sample was stated. Since a distribution is not stated in this problem, I would assume that I would need to use the Central Limit Theorem.

If I let $Y_n$ be a sequence of $X_1,\cdots, X_n$, then could I say $\sqrt{n}(Y_n) \to N(0,1)$ in distribution? I do not know where this would be helpful, but I honestly do not know where to start in solving this problem.

Comment: Recall Slutsky's theorem.

Comment: One way to apply the hint by @Stubborn is to rewrite $$Z_n = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\frac{X_1X_2+\cdots+X_{2n-1}X_{2n}}{\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{X_1^2+\cdots+X_{2n}^2}{2n}}.$$ Consider the limiting behaviors of the numerator and denominator separately.